# About the definition of the product of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $I,J \subset R$ such that $I$ is a left ideal. Let us consider the set

$IJ = \left \{ \displaystyle \sum_1^n i_k j_k \mid n \in \Bbb N, i_k \in I, \; j_k \in J \right \} \tag 1 $

Then is it true that this is a left ideal?

- If $a, b \in IJ$ then, from the fact that $I$ is a left ideal we have that $a-b \in IJ$.
- Let $a \in IJ$ and $r \in R$.  Then $a = \displaystyle \sum_{p=1}^{k} i_p j_p$ , where $k \in \Bbb N$ and $i_p \in I , j_p \in J , \forall p \in \overline{1,k}$ . 
  Because $r \cdot i_p \in I$ , $\forall p \in \overline{1,k}$ it is clear that $ra \in IJ$.

I don't see any mistake here.

My questions are the following:

1. In the definition given [here](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_ideals) , why do we need that $R$ is **commutative** and **unital**?
2. Moreover, can't we define the product of $n$ ideals and the power of an ideal without assuming that $R$ is *commutative* and *unital* ?

Comment: Mainly because the definition is useful (and has good properties) only in the case of commutative unital rings.

Comment: If you have access to a copy of Hungerford's graduate algebra text you can see that he defines sum and product of ideals just as you have mentioned.

Comment: Can you please tell me which page?

Comment: *why do we need that  is commutative and unital* Well it would be downright strange if the commalg.subwiki did not assume commutativity. It would be only slightly less strange to not assume identity.   Commutative algebraists work nearly exclusively with commutative rings with identity.   The *source* has a need for it to have these properties but the definition does not.